# C# Displaying same panel across different tabs

Tags: c#, panel

I have a tabcontrol with multiple tabs and I want a panel that shows progress bar to be visible whenever user is processing something and be hidden when the processing has completed.

I added that panel in first tab of the tabcontrol. However, now the panel will only be visible when user selects the first tab but disappears when user selects other tabs.

I want the panel to display when user selects other tabs. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you maybe add a few screenshots? Surely if you just placed the panel outside of your tabcontrol and then controlled it's visibility as appropriate using the `Visible` property that would do it?

Comment: View + Other Windows + Document Layout.  Click and drag it to the form.  Change the Location by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you talk about WPF, if so, wrap the TabControl in a grid
give the grid 2 childs first tb control second the progress bar, whenever you set the progress bar visibility to visible it'll be on top of screen.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with putting it outside the `TabControl`?